# Invalid handler callback for jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

invalidHandler function doesn't get called on validation on keypress or blur. It gets called when I try to submit the whole form.

Comment: Yes, it is [documented](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) as such. You will have to write a custom validation method for the plugin to behave otherwise.

Comment: I found a solution using showErrors. Instead of doing callback in invalidHandler, I am calling it within showError

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem. Instead of doing a callback on invalidHandler, I am doing it on showErrors. I am doing following:

```
showErrors:function(errorMap,errorList){
    callBackFunction();
    this.defaultShowErrors();     // to display the default error placement
}
```