# function after errors are displayed with jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation. I have just one little problem with the design thanks to the errors that are being shown.
My code for now:

```
 $('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        txtNaam: { required: true },
        txtVoornaam: { required: true },
        txtDatum: { required: true },
        //rdbMan: { require_from_group: [1, ".optionsRadio"] },
        //rdbVrouw: { require_from_group: [1, ".optionsRadio"] },
        txtINSZ: {
            required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked')
        },
        txtGeboorteP:{required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked')},
        txtStraat: { required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked') },
        txtNr: { required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked') },
        txtBNummer: { required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked') },
        txtPost: { required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked') },
        txtWoonP: { required: $('cbInxsz').prop('checked') }
    },
    messages: {
        txtNaam: {
            required:'Please fill in name'
        }
    },
    submitHandler:function(form){
        checkWidth();
        alert("gg");
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //resize because of the errors that are being displayed
        checkWidth();
},

});
```

Now the issue is when the errors are displayed my function checkWidth has to run. with the invalidhandler he doesn't do that because this is runned before the errors are displayed... Anyone has any ideas?

CheckWidth funciton:

```
function checkWidth() {
    w = $window.width();

    if (w <= 650) {
        //width smaller then 650 pixels divs above each other and button in the middle
        $('#div1').removeClass('col-xs-6');
        $('#div1').addClass('col-xs-12');
        $('#div2').removeClass('col-xs-6');
        $('#div2').css('height', 'auto');
        $("#divButton").removeClass("text-right");
        $("#divButton").addClass("text-center");
        $('#btnSubmit').addClass("col-xs-6");
        $('#btnSubmit').removeClass("col-xs-2");

    }
    else {
        //bigger => divs next to each other and button in the right corner
        $('#div1').addClass('col-xs-6');
        $('#div1').removeClass('col-xs-12');
        $('#div2').addClass('col-xs-6');
        $("#div2").height($("#div1").height());
        $("#divButton").addClass("text-right");
        $("#divButton").removeClass("text-center");
        $('#btnSubmit').addClass("col-xs-2");
        $('#btnSubmit').removeClass("col-xs-6");

    }


}
```

Comment: The code seems ok, did you receive any error in the javascript console? Try removing the last comma after the closing } after the checkWidth() call.

Comment: @NetVicious No nothing... The submithandler does it's job thought. I removed the comma but nothing happened.

Comment: The alert('gg') it's run when you got a wrong form ? Please edit your question and paste the checkWidth() function.

Comment: @NetVicious No it doesn't run when there are errors. I added the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invalidHandler function gets called when you try to submit the whole form. Try putting the callback function on showErrors:

```
showErrors:function(errorMap,errorList){
    checkWidth();
    this.defaultShowErrors();     // to display the default error placement
}
```

Got it from this link [Invalid handler callback for jquery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878595/invalid-handler-callback-for-jquery-validation)

Comment: I had to place this.defaultShowErrors(); before my own function but it works now :) thank you very much for your time!